# OpenCV - To resize an image which is present in device memory

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, gpu

I have an image which is present in the device memory I then move the data back to host and when I resize it's working, but when I actually move the device data to the gpumat and then try to resize it doesn't work, can someone please  tell me on what's the mistake. Attaching the working and non working code

```
//Working code
/*Input 
m,n = rows and columns.
dGreal = image present in device memory*/

cuda::GpuMat g_main(m,n, CV_32F, dGreal); 
Mat outputCpu;
g_main.download(outputCpu);
printf("%f \n",outputCpu.at<float>(25,56));


//Not working code
cuda::GpuMat g_main(m,n, CV_32F, dGreal);
cuda::resize(g_main, output_dg, Size(), 0.25, 0.25, CV_INTER_LINEAR); 
// Crashes in the above line.
 printf("%f \n",outputCpu.at<float>(25,56));
```

Error output: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000429fcd0 ***

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fdd7f9ac7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8181e)[0x7fdd7f9b681e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x54)[0x7fdd7f9b85d4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_Znwm+0x18)[0x7fdd80428468]
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2(_ZN2cv4cuda6Stream4ImplC2EP11CUstream_st+0x70)[0x7fdd811eae40]
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2(_ZN2cv4cuda6Stream4NullEv+0xa7)[0x7fdd811ece17]
./FBF[0x40d303]
./FBF[0x40c3f3]
./FBF[0x403b5f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fdd7f955830]
./FBF[0x4045f9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00416000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 8129778                            /home/lisa/Suhas/Review/OPENCV_BOX/box_ComReal/V1/FBF
00615000-00616000 r--p 00015000 08:07 8129778                            /home/lisa/Suhas/Review/OPENCV_BOX/box_ComReal/V1/FBF
00616000-00617000 rw-p 00016000 08:07 8129778                            /home/lisa/Suhas/Review/OPENCV_BOX/box_ComReal/V1/FBF
00a55000-04d82000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
200000000-200100000 rw-s 7c4444000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
200100000-200104000 rw-s ba486000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
200104000-200120000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200120000-200520000 rw-s baef2000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
200520000-200524000 rw-s 78cb6f000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
200524000-200540000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200540000-200940000 rw-s 7bdd6b000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
200940000-200944000 rw-s 7c0aee000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
200944000-200960000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200960000-200d60000 rw-s 78c822000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
200d60000-200d64000 rw-s 7bb465000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
200d64000-200d80000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200d80000-201180000 rw-s 795f2c000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
201180000-201184000 rw-s 34f7e000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
201184000-2011a0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2011a0000-2015a0000 rw-s b9ec2000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
2015a0000-2015a4000 rw-s 4b84d2000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
2015a4000-2015c0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2015c0000-2019c0000 rw-s 7aae96000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
2019c0000-2019c4000 rw-s 75d739000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
2019c4000-2019e0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2019e0000-201de0000 rw-s 76e574000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
201de0000-201de4000 rw-s 7c7757000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
201de4000-201e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
201e00000-202200000 rw-s 7bfc44000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
202200000-202204000 rw-s 34e03000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
202204000-202220000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202220000-202620000 rw-s ba318000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
202620000-202624000 rw-s 7c1132000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
202624000-202640000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202640000-202a40000 rw-s 7c113e000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
202a40000-202a44000 rw-s 7c1349000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
202a44000-202a60000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202a60000-202e60000 rw-s 13f595000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
202e60000-202e64000 rw-s 7c2491000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
202e64000-202e80000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202e80000-203280000 rw-s 7c249d000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
203280000-203284000 rw-s 036cb000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
203284000-2032a0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2032a0000-2036a0000 rw-s bae6f000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
2036a0000-2036a4000 rw-s 4d2e00000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
2036a4000-2036c0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2036c0000-203ac0000 rw-s 3a6dd0000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
203ac0000-203ac4000 rw-s 7c7653000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
203ac4000-203ae0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
203ae0000-203ee0000 rw-s 7c765f000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
203ee0000-203ee4000 rw-s 7bef3a000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
203ee4000-203f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
203f00000-204300000 rw-s 4d2f6e000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
204300000-204400000 rw-s 16f9a000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
204400000-204500000 rw-s bab98000 00:06 479                              /dev/nvidiactl
204500000-204600000 rw-s 7c690f000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
204600000-204700000 rw-s 7c0cb1000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
204700000-204800000 rw-s 7bd894000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
204800000-204900000 rw-s 7bef76000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
204900000-2049e0000 rw-s 7c6e3a000 00:06 479                             /dev/nvidiactl
2049e0000-d00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd68000000-7fdd68021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd68021000-7fdd6c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd6c000000-7fdd6c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd6c021000-7fdd70000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd70000000-7fdd70021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd70021000-7fdd74000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd758e7000-7fdd758e8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd758e8000-7fdd760e8000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd760e8000-7fdd760e9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd760e9000-7fdd768e9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd768e9000-7fdd768ea000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd768ea000-7fdd770ea000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd770ea000-7fdd7712c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 11535991                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.378.13
7fdd7712c000-7fdd7732b000 ---p 00042000 08:05 11535991                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.378.13
7fdd7732b000-7fdd77336000 rw-p 00041000 08:05 11535991                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.378.13
7fdd77336000-7fdd7733b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd7733b000-7fdd77a68000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9440576                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.378.13
7fdd77a68000-7fdd77c67000 ---p 0072d000 08:05 9440576                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.378.13
7fdd77c67000-7fdd77d84000 rw-p 0072c000 08:05 9440576                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.378.13
7fdd77d84000-7fdd77d92000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd77d92000-7fdd77d97000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9445322                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7fdd77d97000-7fdd77f96000 ---p 00005000 08:05 9445322                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7fdd77f96000-7fdd77f97000 r--p 00004000 08:05 9445322                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7fdd77f97000-7fdd77f98000 rw-p 00005000 08:05 9445322                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7fdd77f98000-7fdd77f9a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9445311                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7fdd77f9a000-7fdd7819a000 ---p 00002000 08:05 9445311                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7fdd7819a000-7fdd7819b000 r--p 00002000 08:05 9445311                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7fdd7819b000-7fdd7819c000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 9445311                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7fdd7819c000-7fdd781bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9446689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7fdd781bd000-7fdd783bc000 ---p 00021000 08:05 9446689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7fdd783bc000-7fdd783bd000 r--p 00020000 08:05 9446689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7fdd783bd000-7fdd783be000 rw-p 00021000 08:05 9446689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7fdd783be000-7fdd783cf000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9445324                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7fdd783cf000-7fdd785ce000 ---p 00011000 08:05 9445324                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7fdd785ce000-7fdd785cf000 r--p 00010000 08:05 9445324                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7fdd785cf000-7fdd785d0000 rw-p 00011000 08:05 9445324                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7fdd785d0000-7fdd78705000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9445307                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7fdd78705000-7fdd78905000 ---p 00135000 08:05 9445307                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7fdd78905000-7fdd78906000 r--p 00135000 08:05 9445307                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7fdd78906000-7fdd7890a000 rw-p 00136000 08:05 9445307                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7fdd7890a000-7fdd789c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 11535993                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGLdispatch.so.0
7fdd789c4000-7fdd78bc4000 ---p 000ba000 08:05 11535993                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGLdispatch.so.0
7fdd78bc4000-7fdd78bd3000 rw-p 000ba000 08:05 11535993                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGLdispatch.so.0
7fdd78bd3000-7fdd78bf3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd78bf3000-7fdd78c02000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 11536038                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGLX.so.0
7fdd78c02000-7fdd78e02000 ---p 0000f000 08:05 11536038                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGLX.so.0
7fdd78e02000-7fdd78e03000 rw-p 0000f000 08:05 11536038                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGLX.so.0
7fdd78e03000-7fdd78e23000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd78e23000-7fdd78e2e000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9446041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0
7fdd78e2e000-7fdd7902d000 ---p 0000b000 08:05 9446041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0
7fdd7902d000-7fdd7902e000 r--p 0000a000 08:05 9446041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0
7fdd7902e000-7fdd79031000 rw-p 0000b000 08:05 9446041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0
7fdd79031000-7fdd79052000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3674628                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fdd79052000-7fdd79251000 ---p 00021000 08:05 3674628                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fdd79251000-7fdd79252000 r--p 00020000 08:05 3674628                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fdd79252000-7fdd79253000 rw-p 00021000 08:05 3674628                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fdd79253000-7fdd7926c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3674752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fdd7926c000-7fdd7946b000 ---p 00019000 08:05 3674752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fdd7946b000-7fdd7946c000 r--p 00018000 08:05 3674752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fdd7946c000-7fdd7946d000 rw-p 00019000 08:05 3674752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fdd7946d000-7fdd794a4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9448140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2
7fdd794a4000-7fdd796a4000 ---p 00037000 08:05 9448140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2
7fdd796a4000-7fdd796a5000 r--p 00037000 08:05 9448140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2
7fdd796a5000-7fdd796a7000 rw-p 00038000 08:05 9448140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2
7fdd796a7000-7fdd796aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd796aa000-7fdd79738000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 11536035                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGL.so.1.0.0
7fdd79738000-7fdd79938000 ---p 0008e000 08:05 11536035                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGL.so.1.0.0
7fdd79938000-7fdd79939000 rw-p 0008e000 08:05 11536035                   /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGL.so.1.0.0
7fdd79939000-7fdd7993a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd7993a000-7fdd79941000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3670101                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fdd79941000-7fdd79b40000 ---p 00007000 08:05 3670101                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fdd79b40000-7fdd79b41000 r--p 00006000 08:05 3670101                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fdd79b41000-7fdd79b42000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 3670101                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fdd79b42000-7fdd79b45000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3670105                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fdd79b45000-7fdd79d44000 ---p 00003000 08:05 3670105                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fdd79d44000-7fdd79d45000 r--p 00002000 08:05 3670105                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fdd79d45000-7fdd79d46000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 3670105                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fdd79d46000-7fdd7d9c6000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9440900                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppi.so.7.5.18
7fdd7d9c6000-7fdd7dbc6000 ---p 03c80000 08:05 9440900                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppi.so.7.5.18
7fdd7dbc6000-7fdd7dbd9000 rw-p 03c80000 08:05 9440900                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppi.so.7.5.18
7fdd7dbd9000-7fdd7dc17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd7dc17000-7fdd7dc7c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9440898                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppc.so.7.5.18
7fdd7dc7c000-7fdd7de7c000 ---p 00065000 08:05 9440898                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppc.so.7.5.18
7fdd7de7c000-7fdd7de7f000 rw-p 00065000 08:05 9440898                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppc.so.7.5.18
7fdd7de7f000-7fdd7de80000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd7de80000-7fdd7dedb000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9440814                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.7.5.18
7fdd7dedb000-7fdd7e0da000 ---p 0005b000 08:05 9440814                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.7.5.18
7fdd7e0da000-7fdd7e0de000 rw-p 0005a000 08:05 9440814                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.7.5.18
7fdd7e0de000-7fdd7f675000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9570208                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0
7fdd7f675000-7fdd7f874000 ---p 01597000 08:05 9570208                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0
7fdd7f874000-7fdd7f87d000 r--p 01596000 08:05 9570208                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0
7fdd7f87d000-7fdd7f89e000 rw-p 0159f000 08:05 9570208                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0
7fdd7f89e000-7fdd7f935000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd7f935000-7fdd7faf4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3670106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fdd7faf4000-7fdd7fcf4000 ---p 001bf000 08:05 3670106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fdd7fcf4000-7fdd7fcf8000 r--p 001bf000 08:05 3670106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fdd7fcf8000-7fdd7fcfa000 rw-p 001c3000 08:05 3670106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fdd7fcfa000-7fdd7fcfe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd7fcfe000-7fdd7fd16000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3670112                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fdd7fd16000-7fdd7ff15000 ---p 00018000 08:05 3670112                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fdd7ff15000-7fdd7ff16000 r--p 00017000 08:05 3670112                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fdd7ff16000-7fdd7ff17000 rw-p 00018000 08:05 3670112                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fdd7ff17000-7fdd7ff1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd7ff1b000-7fdd7ff31000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3671409                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fdd7ff31000-7fdd80130000 ---p 00016000 08:05 3671409                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fdd80130000-7fdd80131000 r--p 00015000 08:05 3671409                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fdd80131000-7fdd80132000 rw-p 00016000 08:05 3671409                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fdd80132000-7fdd80194000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 11411963                   /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0.61
7fdd80194000-7fdd80394000 ---p 00062000 08:05 11411963                   /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0.61
7fdd80394000-7fdd80397000 rw-p 00062000 08:05 11411963                   /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0.61
7fdd80397000-7fdd80398000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd80398000-7fdd80512000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9451707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.23
7fdd80512000-7fdd80712000 ---p 0017a000 08:05 9451707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.23
7fdd80712000-7fdd8071c000 r--p 0017a000 08:05 9451707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.23
7fdd8071c000-7fdd8071e000 rw-p 00184000 08:05 9451707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.23
7fdd8071e000-7fdd80722000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd80722000-7fdd80792000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9437680                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4
7fdd80792000-7fdd80992000 ---p 00070000 08:05 9437680                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4
7fdd80992000-7fdd80993000 r--p 00070000 08:05 9437680                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4
7fdd80993000-7fdd80996000 rw-p 00071000 08:05 9437680                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4
7fdd80996000-7fdd809ba000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3674702                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7fdd809ba000-7fdd80bb9000 ---p 00024000 08:05 3674702                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7fdd80bb9000-7fdd80bba000 r--p 00023000 08:05 3674702                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7fdd80bba000-7fdd80bbb000 rw-p 00024000 08:05 3674702                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7fdd80bbb000-7fdd80c12000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9446045                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fdd80c12000-7fdd80e12000 ---p 00057000 08:05 9446045                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fdd80e12000-7fdd80e13000 r--p 00057000 08:05 9446045                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fdd80e13000-7fdd80e14000 rw-p 00058000 08:05 9446045                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fdd80e14000-7fdd80f1c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3670111                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fdd80f1c000-7fdd8111b000 ---p 00108000 08:05 3670111                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fdd8111b000-7fdd8111c000 r--p 00107000 08:05 3670111                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fdd8111c000-7fdd8111d000 rw-p 00108000 08:05 3670111                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fdd8111d000-7fdd8219c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9570199                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0
7fdd8219c000-7fdd8239c000 ---p 0107f000 08:05 9570199                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0
7fdd8239c000-7fdd823a5000 r--p 0107f000 08:05 9570199                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0
7fdd823a5000-7fdd823d3000 rw-p 01088000 08:05 9570199                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0
7fdd823d3000-7fdd823e2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd823e2000-7fdd848e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9570230                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.2.0
7fdd848e6000-7fdd84ae5000 ---p 02504000 08:05 9570230                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.2.0
7fdd84ae5000-7fdd84ae8000 r--p 02503000 08:05 9570230                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.2.0
7fdd84ae8000-7fdd84aeb000 rw-p 02506000 08:05 9570230                    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.2.0
7fdd84aeb000-7fdd84b11000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3670021                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fdd84c94000-7fdd84c95000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd84c95000-7fdd84c96000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84c96000-7fdd84c97000 rw-s 16f95000 00:06 479                        /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84c97000-7fdd84c98000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84c98000-7fdd84c99000 rw-s 7bef39000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84c99000-7fdd84c9a000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84c9a000-7fdd84c9b000 rw-s 7c7652000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84c9b000-7fdd84c9c000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84c9c000-7fdd84c9d000 rw-s 7c282f000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84c9d000-7fdd84c9e000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84c9e000-7fdd84c9f000 rw-s 036ca000 00:06 479                        /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84c9f000-7fdd84ca0000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ca0000-7fdd84ca1000 rw-s 7c2490000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ca1000-7fdd84ca2000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ca2000-7fdd84ca3000 rw-s 7c1348000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ca3000-7fdd84ca4000 rw-s efde6000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ca4000-7fdd84ca5000 rw-s 7c1131000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ca5000-7fdd84ca6000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ca6000-7fdd84ca7000 rw-s 34e01000 00:06 479                        /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ca7000-7fdd84ca8000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ca8000-7fdd84ca9000 rw-s 7c7756000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ca9000-7fdd84caa000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84caa000-7fdd84cab000 rw-s 75d738000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84cab000-7fdd84cac000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84cac000-7fdd84ce3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd84ce3000-7fdd84ce4000 rw-s 4b84d1000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ce4000-7fdd84ce5000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ce5000-7fdd84ce6000 rw-s 34f7d000 00:06 479                        /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ce6000-7fdd84ce7000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ce7000-7fdd84ce8000 rw-s 7bb464000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84ce8000-7fdd84ce9000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ce9000-7fdd84cea000 rw-s 7c0aed000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84cea000-7fdd84ceb000 rw-s efde5000 00:06 480                        /dev/nvidia0
7fdd84ceb000-7fdd84cec000 rw-s 78cb6e000 00:06 479                       /dev/nvidiactl
7fdd84cec000-7fdd84d10000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fdd84d10000-7fdd84d11000 r--p 00025000 08:05 3670021                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fdd84d11000-7fdd84d12000 rw-p 00026000 08:05 3670021                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fdd84d12000-7fdd84d13000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe0abe5000-7ffe0ac05000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]Aborted (core dumped)
```